# Is there any way to get all product variation prices to display?

Tags: wordpress

I have WordPress woo-commerce site with product selling, and i have three variation price for the product like (1 kg -420, 500 grams - 220 and 250 gram- 100). currently it prices are showing like 100-420,  but i need all three variation price to be display below the product, can any one help for this issue

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxhtA.jpg

```
$formatted_price = ( $negative ? '-' : '' ) . sprintf( $args['price_format'], '<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $args['currency'] ) . '</span>', $price );
$return          = '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . $formatted_price . '</span>';

if ( $args['ex_tax_label'] && wc_tax_enabled() ) {
    $return .= ' <small class="woocommerce-Price-taxLabel tax_label">' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
}
```

Comment: Try this https://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/get-woocommerce-product-variation-price-and-sale-price-for-your-pricing-table/

Comment: tried but no use